# How to remove UIBezierPath from UIView on button click?

Tags: ios

I am using following code to create a digital signature on `UIView`:

```
#import "Signature.h"

@implementation Signature {
    UIBezierPath *path;
    UIImage *incrementalImage;
    CGPoint pts[5]; // we now need to keep track of the four points of a Bezier segment and the first control point of the next segment
    uint ctr;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    }
    return self;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect];
    [path stroke];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    ctr = 0;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    pts[0] = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    ctr++;
    pts[ctr] = p;
    if (ctr == 4)
    {
        pts[3] = CGPointMake((pts[2].x + pts[4].x)/2.0, (pts[2].y + pts[4].y)/2.0); // move the endpoint to the middle of the line joining the second control point of the first Bezier segment and the first control point of the second Bezier segment

        [path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
        [path addCurveToPoint:pts[3] controlPoint1:pts[1] controlPoint2:pts[2]]; // add a cubic Bezier from pt[0] to pt[3], with control points pt[1] and pt[2]

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        // replace points and get ready to handle the next segment
        pts[0] = pts[3];
        pts[1] = pts[4];
        ctr = 1;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self drawBitmap];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [path removeAllPoints];
    ctr = 0;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"hello");
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)drawBitmap
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);

    if (!incrementalImage) // first time; paint background white
    {
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
        [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
        [rectpath fill];
    }
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (void)erase {
    NSLog(@"Erase Testing...");
     // self->path   = nil;  //Set current path nil
     //path   = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I am calling erase method on button click but it's not working for me. I don't know why it's not responding.

Comment: Can you show the button code here?

Comment: yes sir ofcourse i call this method from another class  - (IBAction)erase:(id)sender {
    
    NSLog(@"callPrint");
    
    self->printMessage = [[Signature alloc] init];
   [self->printMessage erase];
}

Comment: did you make the IBAction connection?

Comment: yes sir when i press button i print this line in console NSLog(@"Erase Testing..."); it means erase method called

Answer (score 0):

sandeep tomar,

Trying to remove the already drawn UIBezierPath from UIView can be bit cumbersome though absolutely possible.

But I believe the simplest solution would be not trying to remove it and just make it invisible :)

Assume you are drawing on a white canvas then when you want to remove the existing UIBezierPath just stroke it again but this time with white color :)

You can never see a white line drawn on white canvas can you ??? :)

```
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
 [path stroke];
```

**EDIT**

If you want to clear everything in one shot then this might help you :)

```
- (void)erase {
  incrementalImage = nil;
  path   = nil;  //Set current path nil
  path   = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  [self setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```

Try this and lemme know if you still have issues.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for youre response sir, i tried to implement it

Comment: @sandeep-tomar : Any issue with that approach ???  Yes the number of segments and the length of the segments being drawn will increase but that you will have to handle anyway if you are developing drawing or signature capturing apps :) I noticed you are making use of UIViews, UIViews are costly try using CALayer, have two layers CALayer1,CALayer2 as soon as user lifts his finger create image and dump it to below layer and let the top layer be showing user's touch and keep it light weight :) There are plenty of tutorials on it :) Infact I had an app as well in app store using same technique.

Comment: ok sir. Sir can you give some tutorial regrence for this task. because the above solution still not working. i am stuck here to remove it on button click.

Comment: it give me following error when i use your code CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: @sandeep-tomar : Did you tried searching answer for that error it is a very common error there is nothing wrong in solution just the way you used it is wrong. Code above is not just two lines you can copy buddy you will have to write some more code as well :) Search online :)

Comment: ok but its not removing bezierpath from uiview at all. i will handle that error but sir its not executed in my way.

Comment: @sandeep-tomar : Can you try the updated answer ??? The answer I posted above can be of use if you are implementing erreser kind of stuff where you want to erase the line where user touches the screen :) But if you want to delete everything just create a new path and force the view to redraw :)

Comment: i already tried that code sir, but i don't know why its not working. image should be nil, but in my case its not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112649/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-sandeep-tomar).

Comment: should i add image view on uiview?

Comment: to create a digital signature should i create a imageview on it

Comment: sir if you have any other reference than please give me a link, i stuck here form last many hours

Comment: buddy but you are already generating incremental images correct buddy :) When you are finally done your incremental image will contain the whole user signature :) Yes sure you have to generate image thats the only way you can save the user signature :)

Comment: I understand buddy but as I have told already I did 4 years ago I don't have neither code nor the reference  :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)erase {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```